# Can't get out of while true loop with break

Tags: python, terminal

I'm trying to create a small user panel in python and I want it to end when the user press a specific number

It works fine when it's the first time you use the panel, but if you press another number to execute a function, it will execute the function and 20 seconds after, it will reopen the panel. If after that you press 6, it just restarts the panel and won't end the program :/

```
def user_panel():
    """
    User panel to navigate through the program.
    """
    print(colored('\nWelcome to the bike rental program!', 'green', attrs=['bold', 'underline']))
    print('\nPlease select an option:\n1. Rent a bike\n2. Dock a bike\n3. Display the stations\n4. Summary\n5. Execute the maintenance of the defective bikes\n',colored('\r6. Exit', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input('\nEnter your choice: '))
            if choice == 1:
                rent_bike()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel()
            elif choice == 2:
                dock_bike()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel()
            elif choice == 3:
                display_stations()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel()
            elif choice == 4:
                summary()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel()
            elif choice == 5:
                maintenance_defective_bikes()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel()
            elif choice == 6:
                print(colored('\nThank you for using the bike rental program!', 'red', attrs=['reverse']))
                break
            else:
                print(colored('\nPlease enter a valid choice!', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
                user_panel()
        except ValueError:
            print(colored('\nPlease enter a valid choice!', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
            user_panel()
```

I must be missing something but can't manage to find what. Any help would be appreciated ^^

Edit : I was doing recursivity so the loop broke once but not twice :/
Found a fix by removing the `while True`

Comment: You use recursion in the loop, which causes only one layer of functions to jump out of a break at a time.

Comment: The purpose of your while loop is to run the thing again and again, why do you keep calling `user_panel` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the current function again in each loop, which is called recursion in computer science, and it will make your program enter a deeper loop from current loop, and the break statement can only jump out of one loop at a time:

```
def user_panel():
    """
    User panel to navigate through the program.
    """
    print(colored('\nWelcome to the bike rental program!', 'green', attrs=['bold', 'underline']))
    print('\nPlease select an option:\n1. Rent a bike\n2. Dock a bike\n3. Display the stations\n4. Summary\n5. Execute the maintenance of the defective bikes\n',colored('\r6. Exit', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
    while True:
        try:
            choice = int(input('\nEnter your choice: '))
            if choice == 1:
                rent_bike()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel() # <---------------------- recursion
            elif choice == 2:
                dock_bike()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel() # <---------------------- recursion
            elif choice == 3:
                display_stations()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel() # <---------------------- recursion
            elif choice == 4:
                summary()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel() # <---------------------- recursion
            elif choice == 5:
                maintenance_defective_bikes()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
                user_panel() # <---------------------- recursion
            elif choice == 6:
                print(colored('\nThank you for using the bike rental program!', 'red', attrs=['reverse']))
                break
            else:
                print(colored('\nPlease enter a valid choice!', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
                user_panel() # <---------------------- recursion
        except ValueError:
            print(colored('\nPlease enter a valid choice!', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
            user_panel() # <-------------------------- recursion
```

The right thing to do is to delete them, and put the first prompt statement inside the loop:

```
def user_panel():
    """
    User panel to navigate through the program.
    """
    while True:
        print(colored('\nWelcome to the bike rental program!', 'green', attrs=['bold', 'underline']))
        print('\nPlease select an option:\n1. Rent a bike\n2. Dock a bike\n3. Display the stations\n4. Summary\n5. Execute the maintenance of the defective bikes\n',colored('\r6. Exit', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
        try:
            choice = int(input('\nEnter your choice: '))
            if choice == 1:
                rent_bike()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
            elif choice == 2:
                dock_bike()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
            elif choice == 3:
                display_stations()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
            elif choice == 4:
                summary()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
            elif choice == 5:
                maintenance_defective_bikes()
                print("Showing panel in 20 seconds...")
                time.sleep(20)
                print("Executing the user panel...")
                time.sleep(2)
            elif choice == 6:
                print(colored('\nThank you for using the bike rental program!', 'red', attrs=['reverse']))
                break
            else:
                print(colored('\nPlease enter a valid choice!', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
        except ValueError:
            print(colored('\nPlease enter a valid choice!', 'red', attrs=['bold']))
```

Or as stated in the comments area, you can remove the loop and call the function recursively on branches other than option 6, but this is an uncommon practice. Recursion too deep will cause stack overflow (just like the name of this site).

Comment: ... or keep the recursive calls and get rid of the `while` loop. Both works, sometimes you see loops, sometimes recursion, just don't mix the two.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't really pay attention that I was in a recursive function... but this makes sense so I'll change it !

Comment: @tobias_k No, you don't want to use recursion here. It just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Matthias Recursion seems to be the only option in purely functional languages. Fortunately, Python is not.

Comment: I agree that a loop makes more sense, just saying that sometimes you see it like this and sometimes like this, and both can work as long as you don't mix.